# Mongodump fails against a mongodb in secure mode

Tags: mongodb

I am brand new to Mongo and have just set up my first MongoDB Instance/Server. We must run this as secure as possible when it goes to production, so I am running it in secure mode. I am trying to get backups working.

This is also my first post in this forum. Please bear with me.

The command I used:
mongodump --host=localhost --port=27017 --username=useradmin --authenticationDatabase=admin --out=/opt/mongodb/bkup/mongodump-`date +%m%d%yyyy%H%M`.

I get: 
2020-05-11T14:17:06.087-0500    Failed: error creating intents to dump: error creating intents for database admin: error getting collections for database `admin`: (Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command { listCollections: 1, filter: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("b524c139-54d1-4789-a2b3-2eb88bb37255") }, $db: "admin" }

I know my authentication works because I can connect with:
[root@svldstkdb01 bin]# mongo svldstkdb01/admin -u useradmin -p
MongoDB shell version v4.2.6
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://svldstkdb01:27017/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("cc5b1b24-dc00-437d-ae56-6aef53018589") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.6

> show dbs
>   admin   0.000GB  <-- useradmin account is here
>   config  0.000GB
>   local   0.000GB
>   stkdb   0.000GB  <-- I also need to back up this DB.

Questions:

1) Do I need to create an admin account to backup all DBs?
   - Please give an example to create such an account.
2) Is there a way to backup all DBs in the instance?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [backup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#backup) role which provides necessary permissions to do mongodump. To create an user follow example [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/#create-user-with-roles) with role as "backup" or [grant](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/#db-grantrolestouser) existing user backup role